# How can I create the same thing using recyclerview or list view in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

[The list I wanna create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YzkEs.jpg)

I wanna create the same list and when I click it it expands and shows more content
I tried recyclerview with cardview as item or row but didn't work so can I create recyclerview or listview like the same as the Image?
(Note)
I'm talk about the list not the tabs
any ideas please :)

[The list I wanna create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YzkEs.jpg)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Create a Viewpager with tablayout, create fragments and then connect them to your viewpager